# mp4 Splash Screen for android with PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
          VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
          setContentView(videoHolder);
          Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash);
          videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
          videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
              public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                  finish();
              }
          });
          videoHolder.start();
     } catch(Exception ex) {
         finish();
     }
}

public void finish() {
    if(isFinishing()) {
      return;
    }
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);       
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",1000);
}
```

The problem is that this is executing synchronously. When launching the application the "mp4 clip" is playing as a splash screen which is good but once finished a black screen is showing as a loading before having my app home page ready. I want to load the phonegap page in parallel with clip playing in order to have it ready when the clip is finished. Thank u

Comment: i too facing this problem. Have you found any solution to overcome black screen issue?